# A big prank using VBScript

Tags: powershell, vbscript, internet-explorer

So, I have made a BIG prank in VBScript.

First part is to prank with a Dummy HTA splash screen using an encoded PNG image inside it (Not included) and kill all windowed processes+explorer and keep it for a few seconds.

Then launch a internet explorer window in kiosk mode and launch fakeupdate.net according to windows version (Fake update prank)

So, everything is fine on Windows 10.

But I am not sure for Windows XP, because it needs a bit powershell and in Windows 98 it's not definitely gonna work because, You won't have IE6, WMI, Powershell :-(

You can improve this and port it for XP or 9x

Thanks

Whole Code with Base64 PNG image: https://pastebin.com/cPkiWvUW

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,objSelf,objTemp,strTemp,objDummy,strContent
Dim objRegex,objMatches,strMatch,strB64,objLOL,WshShell,iSkip
strB64 = "" : iSkip = 1
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objSelf = fso.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
Set objTemp = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
strTemp = objTemp.Path & "\MSKernel32.vbs"
objSelf.Copy strTemp
Set objDummy = fso.OpenTextFile(strTemp,1,False)
strContent = objDummy.ReadAll
Set objRegex = New RegExp
With objRegex
  .Pattern = "'(.*)"
  .IgnoreCase = True
  .Global = True
End With
Set objMatches = objRegex.Execute(strContent)
strTemp = objTemp.Path & "\WinAPI.hta"
Set objLOL = fso.CreateTextFile(strTemp,True)
With objLOL
  .WriteLine "<html><head>"
  .WriteLine "<hta:application maximizebutton=""no"" border=""thin"""
  .WriteLine "borderstyle=""normal"" selection=""no"" scroll=""no"" caption=""no"">"
  .WriteLine "<script language=""VBScript"">"
  .WriteLine "Sub Window_OnLoad()"
  .WriteLine "Dim iLeft,itop,x,y"
  .WriteLine "x = 510 : y =  400"
  .WriteLine "Window.ResizeTo x,y"
  .WriteLine "iLeft = Window.Screen.AvailWidth/2 - x/2"
  .WriteLine "itop = Window.Screen.AvailHeight/2 - y/2"
  .WriteLine "Window.MoveTo ileft, itop" 
  .WriteLine "End Sub"
  .WriteLine "</script></head>"
  .WriteLine "<body bgcolor=""black"">"
  .WriteLine "<table id=""mytable"" style=""margin-top:25px;margin-left:15px"">"
  .WriteLine "<td><img src="""
  For Each strMatch in objMatches
    If iSkip > 2 Then
      .Write Replace(strMatch,"'","")
    Else
      iSkip = iSkip + 1
    End If
  Next
  .WriteLine """></td></table><br>"
  .WriteLine "<marquee BEHAVIOR=""alternate"" BGCOLOR=""black"">"
  .WriteLine "<font face=""Comic sans MS"" color=""RED"" size=""5""><b>WASIF WAS HERE LOL !!</b></font></marquee>"
  .WriteLine "</body></html>"
End With
With WshShell
  .Run "taskkill /im explorer.exe /f",0,True
  .Run "taskkill /f /fi ""status eq not responding""",0,True
  .Run "powershell -c ""& {ps|?{$_.mainwindowtitle}|kill -fo}""",0,True
  .Run strTemp
  Wscript.Sleep 17000
  .Run "taskkill /im mshta.exe /f",0,True
  .Run "explorer.exe"
End With
Dim objWMIService,strComputer,colItems,colItem,strOS,objRegex,strAllOSes
Dim arrAllOSes,strResult,strOSItem,WshShell,arrURI,iter,objProcessList,objProcess
iter = 0
Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
arrURI = Array("xp","vista","win7","win8","win10ue")
strAllOSes = "Windows XP,Windows Vista,Windows 7,Windows 8,Windows 10"
arrAllOSes = Split(strAllOSes,",")
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer)
Set colItems = objWMIService.InstancesOf("Win32_OperatingSystem")
For Each colItem in colItems
  strOS = colItem.Caption
Next
Set objProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'explorer.exe'")
For Each objProcess in objProcessList
  objProcess.Terminate()
Next
WshShell.Run "taskkill /im explorer.exe /f",0,True
Set objRegex = New RegExp
With objRegex
  .Pattern = ".*Windows XP.*"
  .IgnoreCase = True
  .Global = False
End With
For Each strOSItem In arrAllOSes
  With objRegex
    .Pattern = ".*" & strOSItem & ".*"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = False
  End With
  If objRegex.Test(strOS) Then
    WshShell.Run "iexplore -k fakeupdate.net/" & arrURI(iter)
  End If
  iter = iter + 1
Next
```

**NOTE: At the end of script it has an encoded JPG file in Base64, but it is too large to include, see full code (256 KB) in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/cPkiWvUW**

Comment: im trying to be sure its nothing bad wont crash